# Spring : How to get the username on logout call

Tags: java, spring, session, httpsession

I have the following controller for logout I want to get the name of the logout user how can I acheive this ?

`String userName=(String)session.getAttribute("name");`
this line not working

**Logout Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/session", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> logout(HttpSession session){

        String userName=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println("name: " + userName);
        session.invalidate();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("user logged out");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have currently any Spring projects near me, but as I remember, it could be possible to do it like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

As I said, I'm not sure if it's working. It's been a while since I last used Spring, but let me know if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Component
public class LogoutListener implements 
ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogoutListener.class);

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
    List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = 
event.getSecurityContexts();
    UserDetails ud;
    for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
    {
        ud = (UserDetails) 
securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        logger.info("Logout|Session destroyed User: [{}]", 
ud.getUsername());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please see above answer it is more easy